# How to escape empty space in bamboo command task

Tags: msdeploy, bamboo, webdeploy

I want to make a deploy on a bamboo using msdeploy.exe.

I configure a command to run msdeploy.exe on an agent
and try to run it with an argument:

`-verb:sync -source:contentPath="${bamboo.build.working.directory}" -dest:contentPath="Default Web Site/application-name",ComputerName="http://server/MSDeployAgentService",userName=user-name,password=password -verbose`

This command works well from my local cmd.

However, on a bamboo I got an error:

> Unrecognized argument '"-dest:contentPath="Default'. All arguments must begin with "-"
>   It suggests that treat "Web.." as a second parameter because of an empty space.

I tried few things but without a success:

> **Encode with %20**
>
> "Default Web
>   Site/application-name" -> "Default%20Web%20Site/application-name"
>   
>  Result - Default%20Web%20Site doesn't exist 
>  This works
>   when I were using msbuild.
>
> **Escape with ^**
>
> ^"Default Web Site/application-name^"
>  Result: "Unrecognized
>   argument..."
>
> **Using single quotes '**
>
> 'Default
>   Web Site/application-name'
>  Result: "Unrecognized
>   argument..."

Bamboo documentations says to use: "Argument you want to pass to the command. Arguments with spaces in them must be quoted"
However I already quoted my parameter.

Answer (score 0):

It's probabaly because of 5 years old bamboo issue: https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/BAM-10740

As a workaround you can create powershell script which takes paths as an input parameters and execute it from bamboo eg:

Synchronize.ps1 script:

```
Param(
[Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
[string]$Server,
[Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
[string] $UserName,
[Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
[string] $Password,
[Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
[string]$LocalPath,
[Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
[string]$RemotePath
)

Write-Host "Synchronize contents of $RemotePath on host $Server"

& "C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe" -verb:sync -source:contentPath="$LocalPath" -dest:contentPath="$RemotePath",ComputerName="http://$Server/MSDeployAgentService",userName=$UserName,password=$Password -verbose
```

And add bamboo powershell script task Synchronize.ps1 with parameters eg:

```
-Server ${bamboo.My_Server} -LocalPath '${bamboo.build.working.directory}\Artifacts' -RemotePath 'D:\My app\My folder\' ...
```

The drawback is that you must make sure that web deploy is available on agent host eg. by adding dummy web deploy dump task if you are running bamboo older than 5.13.

Answer (score 0):

This is still an issue in Bamboo.

We were able to work around it using the 'Script Task' and selecting '/bin/sh or cmd.exe' as the *Interpreter*.

For the script body, it was entered just as it would from the command line.

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe" -verb:sync -source:iisApp="${bamboo.build.working.directory}\${bamboo.packagePath}" -dest:iisApp="${bamboo.iisApp}",wmsvc="${bamboo.server}",Username="${bamboo.USERNAME}",Password="${bamboo.PASSWORD}",AuthType="Basic",skipAppCreation=true -enableRule:AppOffline -allowUntrusted:true
```

Bamboo variables were used for all the values that changed between the various applications, and were either coming from the deployment environment variables, or the system variables.